# Is it possible to work on a rails project by two developers working on different OS but on same rails version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version-control, bitbucket

I have this confusion and perhaps it may be basic question. I am planning to work on a Rails project along with a friend who stays in a different location.

We have identified Heroku as our deployment platform and Bitbucket for SCM related activities.

Both me and my friend are new to rails but we are familiar with web development in general.

I m working on a Windows box while he is on a Mac. We both have the same rails version including the gems. However, I'm not sure really sure how do we manage the source code and code integration. The reason I say this is because, when we try to commit the entire code from our systems a few platform specific rails file gets uploaded on the server, thereby rendering the deployment useless.

So my question is if I am on Windows and my friend is on Mac, whats the recommended way of working together on a single RAILS project and deploy it on a common platform to get the same desired functionality.

Comment: Source control... Google Tortoise SVN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by using the source control management (SCM) you selected when you set up your repository.

For instance, if you use git, you would copy your repository using `git clone` (the command is provided via the bitbucket interface by clicking on clone), make your changes, and then `git push` your changes back into the repository.

When you want to code next, execute a `git pull` command to get the latest repo changes and then work and `git push` your changes back to the repo.

For examples see [Bitbuckets fantastic tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Bitbucket+101).

As a side note, bitbucket also supports mercurial, although I haven't used it.

As far as your actual issue, each person will need to make sure the platform dependent files are excluded from your repository. If you're using git, see [the git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) specifically the section on `.gitignore` and [git rm](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm)